# Gitlab custom "/project/edit" page feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab

So I am attempting to extend the functionality for the project settings page at route `/[project_name]/edit`, for which the view file is stored at `app/views/projects/edit.html.haml`.

The problem is that I cannot find the corresponding controller for that view. I've tried modifying `edit.html.haml` and outputting the variables `controller_name` and `action_name` to figure out what renders that specific view. Which outputed the controller name as: "projects" and the action name as "edit".

Which has brought me to `app/controllers/projects_controller.rb` and modifying the `edit` function inside, but none of my ruby instance variables seem to be visible to my view. As a sanity check I've commented out:

```
render 'edit', layout: "project_settings"
```

to check to see if the `app/views/projects/edit.html.haml` even renders... and it does.

So am I even editing the correct file in the first place, or am I off track?

---

Used sources:

http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/development/architecture.html

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html (since I'm new to Rails)

---

I also have not been successful at checking my Rails routes using the following command: `bundle exec rake routes --trace`

**output:**

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rb-inotify
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/config/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

---

## Update

Printing out `params[:id]` in `edit.html.haml`, I found out that the correct route is the following one that I found by running `rake routes`:

`edit_project GET      /:id/edit(.:format)    [no_controller_in_this_column]`

My only question now is: Where can I edit the functionality for this route if there seems to be no controller attached to it?

Comment: The `edit` method of `projects_controller.rb` should map to the route `/projects/:id/edit`. If you open a terminal in the root directory of your project,  typing `rake routes` should list your routes.

Comment: Just tried `rake routes` in app root and got:
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.1.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.3.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
/home/git/gitlab/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: `bundle exec rake routes` should work then.

Comment: Alright, I tried running `bundle exec rake routes` and I'm still getting issues (I've updated the question with the command output). I am afraid of updating Rails or Ruby however since I am afraid of breaking our git server.

Comment: since you are messing with the server you should specify you are in production. just to `export RAILS_ENV=production` and then rake should work.

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu Thank you, that did the trick. I ran `bundle exec rake routes` and I'm able to see all my routes now.